# How do you save ROS tutorial subscriber data?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the "Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)" tutorial it states that in:

```
void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}
```

The message is passed in a boost shared_ptr, which means you can store it off if you want.

How exactly can I use this to store my data in a text file. I have no clue where to begin with this. I went through the boost shared_ptr documentation, but I do not understand it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329114/how-do-you-save-ros-tutorial-subscriber-data?/) by [sw14928](https://answers.ros.org/users/42538/sw14928/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What speaks against doing a normal string write?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    std::ofstream out("output.txt");
    out << msg->data.c_str();
    out.close();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2019-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sw14928](https://answers.ros.org/users/42538/sw14928/) on 2019-07-23**:
Thanks for your advice - it works, but how can I make it print a list? cheers

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2019-07-23**:
std::vectorstd::string str_vector;
and then append msg->data.c_str() each time a message arrive
then for loop on the vector and print the content

**Comment by [sw14928](https://answers.ros.org/users/42538/sw14928/) on 2019-07-23**:
Sorry my C++ is not very good. Would that write my list to a vector, then how would I print that into my file iteratively? use append.msg?